# No values in $_POST variable after Submit HTML form

Tags: php, html

I have a html form, which is sending the data through POST to the php-file, and the php-file should process the data (make a good looking structure) and send it via mail.

But the $_POST variable is completely empty....

I have this small html form:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="formmailer.php">
            <div id="input1">
                <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Ihr Name"> <br>
                <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail"> <br>
            </div>
            <div id="input2">
                 <textarea name="nachricht" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea> <br>
                 <input type="submit" value="" name="submit" id="submit">
             </div>
</form>
```

And formmailer.php uses these variables:

```
<?php // 

if(isset($_POST['nt']) && isset($_POST['ntb'])) 
{


// 
$an = "info@website.de";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$nachricht = $_POST['nachricht'];

// Mailheader UTF-8 
$mail_header = 'From:' . $email . "n";
$mail_header .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "rn";

// create layout
$message = "
Name:       $name 
Email:      $email 
Nachricht:  $nachricht 
";

// send mail
mail($an, $message, $mail_header );
}
else {
   echo("<p>Email delivery failed…</p>");
  }

?>
```

If i use this if-statement

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

the mail is sending, but completely empty.

Am i blind? It should be really easy, shouldn't it?

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['nt']) && isset($_POST['ntb']))`

Comment: where is 'nt' and 'ntb' in the html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
isset($_POST['nt']) && isset($_POST['ntb'])
```

In html I do not find `nt` and `ntb` field.

When you use `isset($_POST["submit"])`. In `Post` array php find `submit` value. But you did not enter any value in the form fields that is why you getting empty value in your mail.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line from `formmailer.php`

```
if (isset($_POST['nt']) && isset($_POST['ntb']))
```

to:

```
if ($_POST)
```

I hope this helps.